# How to programmaticaly check if a text input box inside a web page loaded in WPF Browser has focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, focus, controls

In case my question wasn't all that much self explanatory, here's exactly what I'm trying to do:

1. I have a C# WPF app that uses a WPF web browser control to show some website.
2. The app is running on a touchscreen and I'd like to use an on screen keyboard.
3. I'd like for my keyboard only to be visible when a text can be entered in a text input control rendered inside a text input field (one of a couple) showing in the website page being displayed inside the WPF control, and hidden when no text input field has focus, thus I need a way for text input focus event inside a web page to notify my C# app...or the app to know when such event (text input field got focus) happened and when not.

TIA